# The chain rule problem with second composite

Tags: calculus

If for example i have function $f(x)=\sin(5x)$ I know that i have to use chain rule to differentiate this function. I know that $\sin(u)$ where $u=5x$. So why do i get $5\cos(5x)$ instead of $5x\cos(5x)$?

Comment: You get $5\cos(x)$ because that's the right answer.

Comment: @Bhoot. Not so sure of your !!! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Because $\dfrac{d}{dx}(5x)=5$ not $5x$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the chain rule is
$$
(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x))g'(x)
$$
More specifically that we need to take the derivative of $g(x)$ before we multiply it by $f'(g(x))$ so that we see
$$
f(y) = \sin y \\
g(x) = 5x \\
f(g(x)) = \sin 5x \\
(f(g(x)))' = (\cos 5x)(5)
$$

Answer (score 0):

I have always found the chain rule easier to understand by using Leibniz notation.

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx} = \frac{d\sin(5x)}{dx} = \frac{d\sin(5x)}{d5x}\cdot\frac{d5x}{dx} = [\cos(5x)]\cdot[5] = 5\cos(5x)$$